# Not in scope in Haskell

Tags: haskell, scope, winghci

When I try to compile the code from http://michaeldadams.org/papers/scrap_your_zippers/ScrapYourZippers.hs I get:

```
ScrapYourZipper.hs:249:15: Not in scope: type variable ‘hole’   
ScrapYourZipper.hs:251:27: Not in scope: type variable ‘root’
ScrapYourZipper.hs:252:20: Not in scope: type variable ‘hole’ 
ScrapYourZipper.hs:252:25: Not in scope: type variable ‘root’
```

The part of code where this happend:

```
245    data Context hole root where
246    CtxtNull :: Context a a
247    CtxtCons ::
248      forall rights parent. (Data parent) =>
249        Left (hole -> rights)
250        -> Right rights parent
251        -> Context parent root
252        -> Context hole root
```

Any ideas/pointers to whats wrong?

PS: Sorry for poor naming of the post, coulnd't think of anything meaningfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 248 should be

```
forall rights parent root hole. (Data parent) =>
```

It's possible that GHC used to be more permissive here in older versions ...

Comment: But if I use only root or only hole, It is fine,although I still get error for the other variable.

Comment: It works sorry, I've used only piece of the code when compiling.

Answer (score 4):

I replaced that data declaration with:

```
data Context hole root where
    CtxtNull :: Context a a
    CtxtCons :: (Data parent) => Left (hole -> rights) -> Right rights parent -> Context parent root -> Context hole root
```

(i.e. just remove the `forall` clause) and it compiled.

Comment: Ah yes, removing the `forall` is even simpler.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the whole code? I get a bunch of errors like "Couldn't match expected type ‘hole -> t1’ with actual type ‘t’ because type variable ‘hole’ would escape its scope"

Comment: Post your complete code somewhere (e.g. lpaste/pastebin) and I'll take a look at it. I can compile the ScrapeYourZipper.hs file with the above change.

Comment: It works sorry, I've used only piece of the code when compiling.